# How would you optimize an NxN table?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm looking to optimize a square of data (maximum score), where each row is chosen without replacement. Here's a small example, but I'd like an algorithm which would allow for a 30x30 table.

```
opt_table = data.frame(player = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                       first = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4), 
                       second = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.2), 
                       third = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3))
```

The maximum score would be the highest total when adding the chosen scores by column. Here, it would be 0.5 (A) + 0.7 (B) + 0.3 (C) = 1.5. You can't solve it algorithmically by always taking the maximum row of a given column, because it is without replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which can be solved if you use `lp.assign` from package `lpSolve`, i.e.,

```
library(lpSolve)

z <- lp.assign(-as.matrix(opt_table[-1]))
maxscore <- -z$objval
assignment <- colnames(opt_table[-1])[which(t(z$solution != 0), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
```

and you will see

```
> maxscore
[1] 1.5

> assignment
[1] "first"  "second" "third"
```

Comment: Ha, way better than my solution! At least I hedged about "this might be a standard problem ..." Solves the 30x30 problem in 0.02 seconds ...  I got to an objective function of 57.3 in 50 million iterations, `lp.assign` got 61.03 almost instantaneously.

Comment: Great answer! I'm going to read about assignment problems now lol. Ben, if you think your way was long, you should have seen mine before I decided to post this question. I liked your answer too.

Comment: @BenBolker Haha, thanks! Your attempt is also a very good one :P

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if this is anywhere close to optimal; there might be some clever way to reduce this to a class of known optimization problems. In the meantime, a brute-force Monte Carlo swap + `optim(..., method="SANN")` seems workable.

First, define the objective function and the update function (which randomly swaps two positions).

```r
swap <- function(x,...) {
  s <- sample(length(x), 2, replace=FALSE)
  x[s] <- x[rev(s)]
  return(x)
}
objfun <- function(x,M) {
  sum(M[cbind(x,seq(ncol(M)))])
}
```

I checked that this works on the trivial problem, now let's try it on a 30x30 matrix.

```r
set.seed(101)
M2 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(900)),30)
start <- sample(30)
optim(par=start, fn=objfun, gr=swap, control=list(fnscale=-1, 
                                                  trace=TRUE, maxit=1e6),
      method="SANN", M=M2)
```

(I set `fnscale` to -1 because `optim` likes to minimize. When tracing, the *negative* of the objective function is printed ...)

It starts at a value of 22.1 and gets to 53.06. The last improvement (from 52.31 to 53.06) is found at step 796000.

The best out of a million *random* draws (`r <- replicate(1e6,  objfun(sample(30), M=M2))`) was 39.5.

Tuning the simulated annealing parameters might improve performance. Or you could try some other stochastic global optimization approach (e.g. genetic algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Take the max of each column (exclude the "player" column) and sum them.

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(player = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
           first = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4), 
           second = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.2), 
           third = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3)) %>% 
        summarise_at(vars(-player), funs(max)) %>% 
        rowSums()
```

note that it looks like `0.5 (A) + 0.7 (B) + 0.3 (C) = 1.5` should actually be:
`0.5 (A) + 0.7 (B) + 0.4 (C) = 1.6`

Comment: My fault, I should have explained better. The constraint is that we can only choose one column/row. This is why C uses the third row's 0.3 as its contribution to the formula. A brute force way would be to just try all options, but this because computationally expensive when considering a 30x30 table.